# jQuery popup only show once in foreach loop

Tags: jquery, foreach

First, let me explain the purpose of the popup. I have a list from a database of products, in a foreach loop.

Now I added code so that when you click the product, it opens a new box and shows content about this product. But for some reason, it only works on the first product.

I will post the code here, since I am very bad at jQuery/Javascript. Here is the jquery script:

```
        function myFunction3() {
          var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
          popup.classList.toggle("show");
        }
```

**blade**

```
        <td>
                <div class="popup" onclick="myFunction3()">️
                    <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">
                      @if ($product->id!==3)
                      <img src="{{$product->path}}" alt="{{$product->name}}">
                      @else
                      <audio controls style="width: 95%">
                        <source src="\sounds\Pilishpilish.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
                      Your browser does not support the audio element.
                      </audio>
                      @endif
                      </span>
                </div>
              </td>
```

**css:**

```
        .popup {
          position: relative;
          display: inline-block;
          cursor: pointer;
          -webkit-user-select: none;
          -moz-user-select: none;
          -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
        }
        
        
        .popup .popuptext {
          visibility: hidden;
          width: 160px;
          background-color: #555;
          color: #fff;
          text-align: center;
          border-radius: 6px;
          padding: 8px 0;
          position: absolute;
          z-index: 1;
          bottom: 125%;
          left: -120%;
          margin-left: -80px;
        }
        
       
        .popup .popuptext::after {
          content: "";
          position: absolute;
          top: 100%;
          left: 50%;
          margin-left: -5px;
          border-width: 5px;
          border-style: solid;
          border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
        }
        
    
        .popup .show {
          visibility: visible;
          -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
          animation: fadeIn 1s;
        }
       
        @-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
          from {opacity: 0;} 
          to {opacity: 1;}
        }
        
        @keyframes fadeIn {
          from {opacity: 0;}
          to {opacity:1 ;}
        }
```

I know Id should be unique,but how i can do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is add `this` to `onclick="myFunction3()"` like `onclick="myFunction3(this)"`

And then use

```
function myFunction3(obj) {
  var popup = obj.children[0];
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
```

Now you are pass the clicked element to `myFunction3` and then you can use that to dynamic toggle the class of the first child aka your `span`

**Demo**

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("popup");

var myFunction = function() {
  var ele = this.children[0]
  ele.classList.toggle("show")
};

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  elements[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
}
```

```css
table {
  margin: 100px 0 0 100px
}

.popup {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.popup .popuptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 160px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: -120%;
  margin-left: -80px;
}

.popup .popuptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.popup .show {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
  animation: fadeIn 1s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="popup">️
          <span class="popuptext">
                      <img src="{{$product->path}}" alt="{{$product->name}}" />
                      </span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="popup">️
          <span class="popuptext">
                      <img src="{{$product->path}}" alt="{{$product->name}}" />
                      </span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Jquery Solution:

```
$(".popup").click(function() {
  var popup = $(".popuptext", this);
  popup.toggleClass("show");
})
```

Comment: Thanks, this work fine in desktop ,but in mobile (touch) not active ?

Comment: @KeivanTatari I've updated the demo with javascript method and updated question for jquery that works with mobile